# Sorting a MASSIVE multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array with the following structure. How can I sort this by the order field that's embedded in there?

```
[all_items] => Array (
        [item_type] => Array (
             [item_price] => Array (
                  [item_id] => Array (
                       [item] (Object){
                         [amount] => 75
                         [id] => 1
                         [name] => Bike
                         [order] => 1
                       }
                   )
              )
         )
 )
```

Comment: I don't know what the purpose of setting multi-dimension array if you setting up all your values in the last array. I will suggest you to try flattering your array first.

Comment: Do you want to flatten the array in the process? If so, you could flatten first, and then sort. If not, what should happen to `[[[[1],[3]],[[2]]]]`)

Comment: @Rikesh *"Hey, array. You're really looking good today!"* - Like this? ;P

Comment: @ytrew Sort by what? Where? How? Which of the dimensions has more than one entry? What do you expect the result to look like?

Comment: @deceze "sort this by the order field" (I agree there are missing details). I am assuming all dimensions have unspecified size.

Comment: Also, (perhaps most importantly,) this is the kind of thing a database should be doing, not a PHP script

Comment: It's a Drupal array I'm working with. That should explain a lot ;)

Answer (score 1):

`usort` can accept a function to sort by. You can use this to sort the array.

```
usort($array, function($a,$b){
   return reset(reset(reset($a)))->order - reset(reset(reset($b)))->order;
});
```

(Note passing a function like this requires PHP 5.3. Replace this with a method name if < 5.3)

Hopefully someone can come up with something a bit less ugly.

As Rikesh pointed out, unless there's a reason you need such a deeply nested array then flattening it a bit will make it easier to work with.